# Get cookie and set context generic view

Tags: django, cookies, django-generic-views

I am implementing a duplicate vote checking. I set a cookie in the vote view:

```
# Set duplicate vote cookie.
half_year = timedelta(weeks=26)
expires = datetime.utcnow() + half_year
if cookie and re.match(cookie_pattern, cookie):
    redirect.set_cookie(cookie_name, "{}-{}".format(cookie, question.id), expires=expires)
else:
    redirect.set_cookie(cookie_name, question.id, expires=expires)
```

Now I want to access the cookie and than set a context variable in a generic details view. Is this possible or do I have to write a not generic one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resultion was to override getcontextobject:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Check duplicate vote cookie
    cookie = self.request.COOKIES.get(cookie_name)
    if has_voted(cookie, self.object.id):
        context['voted'] = True
    return context
```